# migrated to swift 3 now getting error "argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

i've searched and read many topics that seem to have this same issue but I am unable to find any examples similar to mine.  I just converted an existing project from swift 2.x (can't remember which version) to Xcode8/swift 3.  The code is live in the app store so clearly was working before.

Now I'm getting the following error on what seems to be a very straightforward variable initializer statement.  Please see my code below:

```
//GLOBAL VARIABLES - NEW-------------------------------------

var userEmail = NSString()
var userName = NSString()
var userPassword = NSString()
var userNamePass = NSString()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var loginUserName: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var loginPassword: UITextField!


 @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    userName = NSString(loginUserName.text)  //throws error "argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads
    userPassword = NSString(loginPassword.text)  //throws error "argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads
    userNamePass = NSString("\(userName.uppercased)\(userPassword.uppercased)")   //throws error "argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads


//other code in the login function

} //end login function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a major change in Swift 3

- It's required that all methods / functions provide a label for the first parameter. It's possible to suppress that rule by the underscore character but Apple changed all relevant methods to conform to that rule. So you have to write

  ```
  userName = NSString(string:loginUserName.text)
  ```

The other issue occurs because `uppercased` has been changed to `uppercased()`

---

Why do you create a `String` from something which is a `String` anyway?

By the way, this is Swift. Use `String` rather than `NSString`.

```
var userEmail = ""
var userName = ""
var userPassword = ""
var userNamePass = ""

userName = loginUserName.text ?? "" 
userPassword = loginPassword.text ?? ""
userNamePass = userName.uppercased() + userPassword.uppercased()
```

Comment: I had used NSString because i didn't think that .uppercase methods were available on the String type.  i have converted to String and that seems to have resolved the immediate issue.  appreciate the tip.

Comment: While this provides good suggestions, it doesn't actually answer the question being asked. I would update the answer to explain what was wrong and how to fix it, then offer this suggestion as the proper way to write the code.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy.   I came back to post the same thing...I need to understand what changed in swift 3 to now throw an error on a line ofcode that worked fine in swift 2.x.  Converting something to a new type is pretty standard stuff so I'm very surprised to see this throw an error.   Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "string:" argument label to all the NSString initializer calls. For example, the following code works on a Playgrounds (XCode 8 GM with Swift 3):

```
let userName = NSString(string: "hello")
print(userName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "string:" inside the initializer.

`userName = NSString(string: loginPassword.text)`

Also if loginPassword.text is optional it may need to be unwrapped.

Comment: This is very helpful and helps explain what may have changed in swift 3 in regards to converting a variable to a different type.